# Why the PHP code assigning to an array hangs?

Tags: php, mysql

i'm completely new to PHP. I have prepared (based on various internet sources) a page taking data from mysql database and displaying them using flot to a graph. For *single* database table loaded it works great. However I'm turning that code to 'multitable' load as I want to have multiple graphs per single web page.

The mentioned code is here:

```
<?php
// this retrieves the data from a single page
$servername = "dbserver";
$username = "dbuser";
$password = "dbpassword";
$dbname = "mydatabase";
$port = 5511;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $port);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// time in microseconds
$timenow = time()*1e6;
// start time 8 hours ago
$timestart = intval($timenow - (8*60*60*1e6));

$tables = array("cfoua47bccmb1a_stat", "cfoua47bccmb2a_stat", "cfoua47bccmb1b_stat", "cfoua47bccmb2b_stat");

$sql = "";
foreach ($tables as $table) {
// add each select command to a single query
$sql .= "SELECT time, energy,ABS1TMIN,ABS1TMAX,ABS1TAVG,ABS4TMIN,ABS4TMAX,ABS4TAVG,ABS16TMIN,ABS16TMAX,ABS16TAVG,ABS64TMIN,ABS64TMAX,ABS64TAVG,ABS256TMIN,ABS256TMAX,ABS256TAVG,ABS1024TMIN,ABS1024TMAX,ABS1024TAVG,DIFF1TMIN,DIFF1TMAX,DIFF1TAVG,DIFF4TMIN,DIFF4TMAX,DIFF4TAVG,DIFF16TMIN,DIFF16TMAX,DIFF16TAVG,DIFF64TMIN,DIFF64TMAX,DIFF64TAVG,DIFF256TMIN,DIFF256TMAX,DIFF256TAVG,DIFF1024TMIN,DIFF1024TMAX,DIFF1024TAVG,THR1,THR4,THR16,THR64,THR256,THR1024 FROM " . $table . " WHERE time >=" . $timestart . ";";
}

$alldevices = array();
$index = 0;

if ($conn->multi_query($sql)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $conn->store_result()) {
            // generate for each device a separate dictionary
            echo $tables[$index];
            $alldevices[$tables[$index]] = array();
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
                // assign the value to the dictionary
                $alldevices[$tables[$index]][] = $row;
                //var_dump ($alldevices);

            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($conn->more_results()) {
            $index = $index + 1;
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($conn->next_result());
}

var_dump ($alldevices);


// THIS CODE NICELY WORKS FOR A SINGLE GRAPH AND WAS REPLACED
// BY THE CODE ABOVE TO FETCH AND PREPARE JSON DATA FOR ALL THE
// TABLES

// $result = $conn->query($sql);
// // json convert
// $rows = array();
// if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
//     // output data of each row
//     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
//         // one by one copy into rows
//         $rows[] = $row;
//     }
// }
$conn->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Beam Current Change Monitors</title>
    <link href="./examples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./flot/jquery.flot.navigate.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./flot-axislabels/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
var graphdata = <?php echo json_encode( $rows ) ?>;
var a1t = [];
var a4t = [];
var a16t = [];
var a64t = [];
var a256t = [];
var a1024t = [];
var d1t = [], d4t = [], d16t = [], d64t = [], d256t = [], d1024t = [], energy = [];

// for localtime conversion
var nd = new Date();
var nt = nd.getTimezoneOffset();
for (var m in graphdata){
            energy.push ( [graphdata[m]['time'] / 1e3 - nt*60*1000,graphdata[m]['energy']] );
            a1t.push ( [graphdata[m]['time'] / 1e3 - nt*60*1000,graphdata[m]['ABS1TMAX']] );
            a4t.push ( [graphdata[m]['time'] / 1e3 - nt*60*1000,graphdata[m]['ABS4TMAX'] / 4] );
            a16t.push ( [graphdata[m]['time'] / 1e3 - nt*60*1000,graphdata[m]['ABS16TMAX']/16 ]  );
            a64t.push ( [graphdata[m]['time'] / 1e3 - nt*60*1000,graphdata[m]['ABS64TMAX']/64 ]  );
            a256t.push ( [graphdata[m]['time'] / 1e3 - nt*60*1000,graphdata[m]['ABS256TMAX']/256 ]  );
            a1024t.push ( [graphdata[m]['time'] / 1e3 - nt*60*1000,graphdata[m]['ABS1024TMAX']/1024 ]  );
            d1t.push ( [graphdata[m]['time'] / 1e3 - nt*60*1000,graphdata[m]['DIFF1TMAX']] );
            d4t.push ( [graphdata[m]['time'] / 1e3 - nt*60*1000,graphdata[m]['DIFF4TMAX']/4 ]  );
            d16t.push ( [graphdata[m]['time'] / 1e3 - nt*60*1000,graphdata[m]['DIFF16TMAX']/16 ]  );
            d64t.push ( [graphdata[m]['time'] / 1e3 - nt*60*1000,graphdata[m]['DIFF64TMAX']/64 ]  );
            d256t.push ( [graphdata[m]['time'] / 1e3 - nt*60*1000,graphdata[m]['DIFF256TMAX']/256 ]  );
            d1024t.push ( [graphdata[m]['time'] / 1e3 - nt*60*1000,graphdata[m]['DIFF1024TMAX']/1024 ]  );
        }

// two plots to produce
$.plot("#abs", [
    {data:energy, label:"Energy", yaxis:2},
    {data:a1t, label: "1T"},
    {data:a4t, label: "4T"},
    {data:a16t, label: "16T"},
    {data:a64t, label: "64T"},
    {data:a256t, label: "256T"},
    {data:a1024t, label: "1024T"}
], {
           xaxes: [ { mode: "time", axisLabel: 'Time [h]',axisLabelUseCanvas: true} ],
 yaxes: [ {min:0, axisLabel: "ADC bins [-]", axisLabelUseCanvas: true}, {min:0, max:7000, position: "right"} ],
 legend: {position: "nw"}
 });

$.plot("#diff", [
    {data:d1t, label: "1T"},
    {data:d4t, label: "4T"},
    {data:d16t, label: "16T"},
    {data:d64t, label: "64T"},
    {data:d256t, label: "256T"},
    {data:d1024t, label: "1024T"}
], {
           xaxis: { mode: "time", axisLabel: 'Time [h]',axisLabelUseCanvas: true},
 yaxis: {axisLabel: 'ADC bins [-]', axisLabelUseCanvas: true, min:0, max: 1e5},
 legend: {position: "nw"}
       });

    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h3>CFO-UA47-BCCM-B1A</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <div class="demo-container">
            <div id="abs" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="demo-container">
            <div id="diff" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now the mystery: in the PHP section I'm trying to assemble a dictionary, where each of the processed $tables will be used as a key, and such dictionary would contain array of results returned by sql query.

*Problem is*, that when I issue the line:

```
$alldevices[$tables[$index]][] = $row;
```

the PHP engine from unknown reasons hangs. I.e. it does not load all the values from the table and just stops working. When this line is removed from the code, the code is processed OK (hence all 4 SQL queries are performed and entire page is executed currently displaying only two empty graphs). However if I leave that code there and I print for example $row[0] in each iteration of fetch_row(), I can see that it loads fully the first table, but only partially the second table, and then it hangs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Web PHP isn't a desktop app. Just make the SQL queries for your dictionary as needed (ajax perhaps). You gain nothing and lose everything by loading the whole database up into memory on every request (that's assuming you can even get it to work).

Comment: How much memory would this line allocate? Given that one array entry needs around 160 bytes of memory just for pointers, you might be very quickly out of memory. Depending on how your PHP is configured, it might not complain about reaching that limit, because it is way beyond the physically installed memory in your server - so the server will try to allocate virtual memory, and instantly stop being responsive because it swaps memory to disk.

Comment: Try a separate mysqli::query() for each table, with mysqli_result::free() for each result.

Comment: Dear all, I'm suspicious that it might be a memory allocation problem. I've ran it not on centrally hosted servers, but on my local machine, and there this fragment of core runs OK. Developerwjk, could you comment more on how to make SQL requests as needed?

Answer (score 0):

just for sake of the completeness I give the solution to the problem. So the main reason for all this was the memory available. So according to developerjwk's advice I have reimplemented the engine into two separate steps:

1) the PHP script sitting in a separate file, which fetches needed data from the MySQL database:

```
<?php

function loadData($tablename) {
    // this retrieves the data from a single page
    $servername = "myserver";
    $username = "myusername";
    $password = "somefancypassword";
    $dbname = "databasename";
    $port = 5511;

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $port);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // time in microseconds
    $timenow = time()*1e6;
    // start time 8 hours ago
    $timestart = intval($timenow - (8*60*60*1e6));
    // define array of variables to select
    $variables = array("time", "energy","ABS1TMIN","ABS1TMAX","ABS1TAVG","ABS4TMIN","ABS4TMAX","ABS4TAVG","ABS16TMIN","ABS16TMAX","ABS16TAVG","ABS64TMIN","ABS64TMAX","ABS64TAVG","ABS256TMIN","ABS256TMAX","ABS256TAVG","ABS1024TMIN","ABS1024TMAX","ABS1024TAVG","DIFF1TMIN","DIFF1TMAX","DIFF1TAVG","DIFF4TMIN","DIFF4TMAX","DIFF4TAVG","DIFF16TMIN","DIFF16TMAX","DIFF16TAVG","DIFF64TMIN","DIFF64TMAX","DIFF64TAVG","DIFF256TMIN","DIFF256TMAX","DIFF256TAVG","DIFF1024TMIN","DIFF1024TMAX","DIFF1024TAVG","THR1","THR4","THR16","THR64","THR256","THR1024");
    // loopvars - to iterate when generating arrays
    $loopvars = array_slice($variables,1);

    // sql to fetch the data for a single system
    $sql = "SELECT " . join(',', $variables) . " FROM " . $tablename . " WHERE time >=" . $timestart . ";";

    // generate dictionary of arrays
    foreach ($loopvars as $var) {
        echo "myarray['".$var."']=[];";
    }

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            // one by one copy into rows
            foreach ($loopvars as $var) {
                echo "myarray['".$var."'].push( [". $row['time']/1e3 . "," . $row[$var] . "] );" ;
            }
        }
    }
    $conn->close();
}

?>
```

As you can see, the PHP script does not generate any variables, but generates a javascript code, which fills a 'myarray' variable inside the javascript.

Then I have setup a new index.php page, which by consecutive calls to the PHP script generates data in myarray and plots them using flot:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Beam Current Change Monitors</title>
        <link href="./examples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./flot/jquery.flot.navigate.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./flot-axislabels/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // this is tables array to display accompanied with ymax restriction
            var tables = new Array (["cfoua47bccmb1a_stat", 1e8], ["cfoua47bccmb2a_stat", 1e8], ["cfoua47bccmb1b_stat", 1e8], ["cfoua47bccmb2b_stat", 1e8]);

            var myarray = new Array();
            // NOTE: unfortunately we now need to dumbly copy this block 4 times. This is because we are not able to change
            // the argument in PHP function loadData dynamically. This function is evaluated at the server side. The only
            // way we could use it dynamically is to call php script through ajax, however then there is an issue with passing
            // arguments back to javascript. Instead, call to loadData generates javascript code, which fills the myarray variable by
            // data loaded from the database.
            //console.log("my object: %o", myarray);
            <?php include 'fetchdata.php';loadData("cfoua47bccmb2a_stat");?>
            //console.log("my object: %o", myarray);
            $.plot("#abscfoua47bccmb2a_stat", [{data:myarray['ABS1TMAX'], label: "1T"}, {data:myarray['ABS4TMAX'], label: "4T"},{data:myarray['ABS16TMAX'], label: "16T"},{data:myarray['ABS64TMAX'], label: "64T"},{data:myarray['ABS256TMAX'], label: "256T"},{data:myarray['ABS1024TMAX'], label: "1024T"}], {xaxis: { mode: "time", axisLabel: 'Time [h]',axisLabelUseCanvas: true}, yaxis:{axisLabel: 'ADC bins [-]', axisLabelUseCanvas: true}} );
            $.plot("#diffcfoua47bccmb2a_stat", [{data:myarray['DIFF1TMAX'], label: "1T"}, {data:myarray['DIFF4TMAX'], label: "4T"},{data:myarray['DIFF16TMAX'], label: "16T"},{data:myarray['DIFF64TMAX'], label: "64T"},{data:myarray['DIFF256TMAX'], label: "256T"},{data:myarray['DIFF1024TMAX'], label: "1024T"}], {xaxis: { mode: "time", axisLabel: 'Time [h]',axisLabelUseCanvas: true}, yaxis:{axisLabel: 'ADC bins [-]', axisLabelUseCanvas: true, min:0, max: 1e8}} );

            // make it empty again and run for B2A
            myarray = [];
            <?php  loadData("cfoua47bccmb1a_stat");?>
            $.plot("#abscfoua47bccmb1a_stat", [{data:myarray['ABS1TMAX'], label: "1T"}, {data:myarray['ABS4TMAX'], label: "4T"},{data:myarray['ABS16TMAX'], label: "16T"},{data:myarray['ABS64TMAX'], label: "64T"},{data:myarray['ABS256TMAX'], label: "256T"},{data:myarray['ABS1024TMAX'], label: "1024T"}], {xaxis: { mode: "time", axisLabel: 'Time [h]',axisLabelUseCanvas: true}, yaxis:{axisLabel: 'ADC bins [-]', axisLabelUseCanvas: true}} );
            $.plot("#diffcfoua47bccmb1a_stat", [{data:myarray['DIFF1TMAX'], label: "1T"}, {data:myarray['DIFF4TMAX'], label: "4T"},{data:myarray['DIFF16TMAX'], label: "16T"},{data:myarray['DIFF64TMAX'], label: "64T"},{data:myarray['DIFF256TMAX'], label: "256T"},{data:myarray['DIFF1024TMAX'], label: "1024T"}], {xaxis: { mode: "time", axisLabel: 'Time [h]',axisLabelUseCanvas: true}, yaxis:{axisLabel: 'ADC bins [-]', axisLabelUseCanvas: true, min:0, max: 1e8}} );


            // make it empty again and run for B1B
            myarray = [];
            <?php loadData("cfoua47bccmb1b_stat");?>
            //console.log("my object: %o", myarray);
            $.plot("#abscfoua47bccmb1b_stat", [{data:myarray['ABS1TMAX'], label: "1T"}, {data:myarray['ABS4TMAX'], label: "4T"},{data:myarray['ABS16TMAX'], label: "16T"},{data:myarray['ABS64TMAX'], label: "64T"},{data:myarray['ABS256TMAX'], label: "256T"},{data:myarray['ABS1024TMAX'], label: "1024T"}], {xaxis: { mode: "time", axisLabel: 'Time [h]',axisLabelUseCanvas: true}, yaxis:{axisLabel: 'ADC bins [-]', axisLabelUseCanvas: true}} );
            $.plot("#diffcfoua47bccmb1b_stat", [{data:myarray['DIFF1TMAX'], label: "1T"}, {data:myarray['DIFF4TMAX'], label: "4T"},{data:myarray['DIFF16TMAX'], label: "16T"},{data:myarray['DIFF64TMAX'], label: "64T"},{data:myarray['DIFF256TMAX'], label: "256T"},{data:myarray['DIFF1024TMAX'], label: "1024T"}], {xaxis: { mode: "time", axisLabel: 'Time [h]',axisLabelUseCanvas: true}, yaxis:{axisLabel: 'ADC bins [-]', axisLabelUseCanvas: true, min:0, max: 1e8}} );

            // run B2B
            myarray = [];
            <?php loadData("cfoua47bccmb2b_stat");?>
            //console.log("my object: %o", myarray);
            $.plot("#abscfoua47bccmb2b_stat", [{data:myarray['ABS1TMAX'], label: "1T"}, {data:myarray['ABS4TMAX'], label: "4T"},{data:myarray['ABS16TMAX'], label: "16T"},{data:myarray['ABS64TMAX'], label: "64T"},{data:myarray['ABS256TMAX'], label: "256T"},{data:myarray['ABS1024TMAX'], label: "1024T"}], {xaxis: { mode: "time", axisLabel: 'Time [h]',axisLabelUseCanvas: true}, yaxis:{axisLabel: 'ADC bins [-]', axisLabelUseCanvas: true}} );
            $.plot("#diffcfoua47bccmb2b_stat", [{data:myarray['DIFF1TMAX'], label: "1T"}, {data:myarray['DIFF4TMAX'], label: "4T"},{data:myarray['DIFF16TMAX'], label: "16T"},{data:myarray['DIFF64TMAX'], label: "64T"},{data:myarray['DIFF256TMAX'], label: "256T"},{data:myarray['DIFF1024TMAX'], label: "1024T"}], {xaxis: { mode: "time", axisLabel: 'Time [h]',axisLabelUseCanvas: true}, yaxis:{axisLabel: 'ADC bins [-]', axisLabelUseCanvas: true, min:0, max: 1e8}} );
        });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h1 align="center">BCCM status panel</h1>
        </div>
        <h2 align="center">operational systems</h2>
        <div class="demo-container" style="width:100%; display:table;">
            <div style="display: table-row">
                <div style="display:table-cell;"><h3 align="center">CFO-UA47-BCCM-B1A</h3></div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;"><h3 align="center">CFO-UA47-BCCM-B2A</h3></div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: table-row">
                <div id="abscfoua47bccmb1a_stat" class="demo-placeholder" style="width:45%; display:table-cell;"></div>
                <div id="abscfoua47bccmb2a_stat" class="demo-placeholder" style="width:45%; display:table-cell;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="demo-container" style="width:100%; display:table;">
            <div style="display: table-row">
                <div id="diffcfoua47bccmb1a_stat" class="demo-placeholder" style="width:45%; display:table-cell;"></div>
                <div id="diffcfoua47bccmb2a_stat" class="demo-placeholder" style="width:45%; display:table-cell;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2 align="center">development systems</h2>
        <div class="demo-container" style="width:100%; display:table;">
            <div style="display: table-row">
                <div style="display:table-cell;"><h3 align="center">CFO-UA47-BCCM-B1B</h3></div>
                <div style="display:table-cell;"><h3 align="center">CFO-UA47-BCCM-B2B</h3></div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: table-row">
                <div id="abscfoua47bccmb1b_stat" class="demo-placeholder" style="width:45%; display:table-cell;"></div>
                <div id="abscfoua47bccmb2b_stat" class="demo-placeholder" style="width:45%; display:table-cell;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="demo-container" style="width:100%; display:table;">
            <div style="display: table-row">
                <div id="diffcfoua47bccmb1b_stat" class="demo-placeholder" style="width:45%; display:table-cell;"></div>
                <div id="diffcfoua47bccmb2b_stat" class="demo-placeholder" style="width:45%; display:table-cell;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="footer">
            Issues? mail to: <a href="mailto:david.belohrad@cern.ch?Subject=Issue%20with%20BCCM%20web%20page" target="_top">david.belohrad@cern.ch</a>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it is a bit flimsy as I'm copying 4 times the same loading and plotting block. Unfortunately I did not find any other way how to call PHP script with variable passed into the function. PHP script is server executed and hence the only way how to do this would be maybe AJAX.

Anyways, this works. Results can be seen (so far) on 
http://www.cern.ch/bccm